# Lateral play in Crankset

Tags: crankset, drivetrain, 26-inch, 1x10

I'm converting a ~2006 Scott Reflex to a 1x drive train, following the instructions on this video:

[Convert From Square Taper to Hollowtech II Bottom Bracket/Crankset - RJ the Bike Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcyaSEAhI5k)

However I am getting lateral play in the Crankset, as pictured below:

[image: Picture of Crankset]

Do I need an extra spacer or an I doing something wrong in installation?

Comment: How wide is the bottom bracket shell, and how many spacers (and where) are you using? Are there more spacers on the drive side?

Comment: Pretty sure the shell width is 68 mm?? (original bb was BB-Un26 68 BC1.37x24 DI / LL113) - just a single spacer on each side - the black on on the inside of the BB like in the original picture

Comment: What crankset? If it's a MTB crankset (which I am assuming it is), you need TWO spacers on the drive side and one on the non-drive side. I think that would fix your problem right there. All three should be standard 2.5mm spacers.

Comment: It's a Deore MTB crankset. Is the type of spacers you are referring to? https://www.ramcycleparts.com.au/bottom-bracket-spacer-alloy-2.5mm-x-35mm-id-presti

Comment: Yeah, that's it. If you bought that BB52 new, it should have come with three though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want to confirm [MaplePanda](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/38536/maplepanda) was correct, I picked up another spacer from the LBS and it fixed the issue.

So 2x Spacers on the drive side, 1x on the non-drive side